# Order array items based on their occurrence desc in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of mysql records in **$allrecords** variable.

There are multiple keys for each record and one of the key is called **type**.

Some of the variable has the same type.

E.g. it looks like this:

```
Seat
Mercedes
BMW
BMW
Mercedes
Audi
Mercedes
Fiat
Mercedes
Audi
Fiat
Mercedes
```

The array is unordered now (just grabbed from database) and now I need to order the array items from the most occurance one to the least.

E.g. like this

```
Mercedes (5)
Audi (3)
BMW (2)
Fiat (2)
Seat (1)
```

I do not need the numbers (that I get using another foreach loop), so I need it just like this:

```
Mercedes
Audi
BMW
Fiat
Seat
```

How to do such this in PHP? Is it possible? I need to group the items based on the type and then order them from the most to the least occurance.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:
My array look like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 125
            [user_id] => 29
            [show] => 1
            [state] => 1
            [type] => 23
            [subcat_id] => 11
            [category_id] => 2
            [name] => SLK 350


        )


)
```

Comment: Do you store it in database as `Mercedes (5)`?

Comment: If you're getting that from a database, then have the database do the sorting.

Comment: @MarcB I need it to bedone outside of the database for various purposes

Comment: @zerkms no, just like mercedes. i have edited my post to ake it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$groups = array();
foreach($allrecords as $record){
    $type = $record->type;
    if(empty($groups[$type]))
        $groups[$type] = 1;
    else
        $groups[$type]++;
}

asort ($groups);
$cars = array_keys($groups);
print_r($cars);
```

Comment: It gives me something like Array ( [0] => 8 ) ;(

Comment: but c'mon you said "type" is the property you want to check for occurence -- in your model it's "name"???
maybe you have to change the line "$type = ..." do the proper value.

function counts them with "array-keys => count" relation in array, sorts it associative and "array_keys" extracts the words in correct order...

Comment: Mercedes, audi etc are stored as integers in my db. the name is not important at all. i need sort them based on the type.

Comment: Ok, thanks it seems to work. i have slightly modified it to $allrecords->result() as $record because I am inside codeigniter and it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($allrecords, function($a, $b){ return $a->count >= $b->count; });
```

where "count" is the name of the property...

Comment: hmm, it is not working. I tried usort($allrecords, function($a, $b){ return $a->type >= $b->type ; }); but nothing shows up

Comment: you should give us the real data-format of the array (the result of the query)...

Comment: I have updated my post so you will see how the structure of my variable looks like when using print_r

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(str_word_count(implode(" ", $all_records))); // Returns array( "Mercedes" => 5 ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

aaaah i didn't get that!!!

you should use SQL to achieve this!!!

```
SELECT type, COUNT(1) FROM cars GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: I need it do in php for various reasons.